# How to load html file in webview on Android 11+ using Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android, webview, storage-access-framework

I have application which displays content of html files in WebView from local storage. I use standard paths, example :

myWebView.loadUrl("file:///storage/emulated/0/myfolder/myfile.html");

On android 11+ I must use SAF. I can get uri to the file. But how can I pass it to WebView? Or how can I load content of html file in WebView using SAF?

EDIT: I see what is wrong. First file (index.html) is loaded correctly. This is it's uri:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/9C33-6BBD%3AGames/document/9C33-6BBD%3AGames%2FWalkthroughs%2Fdoom%2Findex.html
```

However, it contains local links. WebView callbacks

```
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       view.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

And there is problem. Incoming "String url" is in incorrect format, it is not in correct uri. This is what comes:

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/9C33-6BBD%3AGames/document/www.abcgames.sk/wsdindex.html@p=navody_zobraz&id=4004.html
```

The real path is :

```
/storage/9C33-6BBD/Games/Walkthroughs/doom/www.abcgames.sk/wsdindex.html@p=navody_zobraz&id=4004.html
```

This is how it was dumped to disk with some web downloader application.

Comment: "But how can I pass it to WebView?" -- did you try just passing it to `loadUrl()` as a parameter?

Comment: Yes of course, it is not loaded.

Comment: I see what is wrong. I updated my question. Problem are links in the main file which are not correctly translated to uri. Maybe I should encode it somehow

Comment: "This is how it was dumped to disk with some web downloader application" -- that's very unlikely to work.

Comment: Why? You play offline game and you need walkthrough. So you can download html or part of website. This is common for old school players.

Comment: `"String url" is in incorrect format, it is not in correct uri.;` It is perfectly done by the WebView. You can say nothing of that. It is only an invalid uri as you did not get it from saf. Webview just placed the querystring after the url. That is what browsers do. No difference if the url starts with "file://"or "content://". The same trouble will happen if you have a html page with images `<img>`. Then also the produced content scheme is invalid.

Comment: All right, I understand now. I must cut the appended part and encode slashes etc. Then it could work.

Comment: No, you will not get it to work as it is like i said it is: you have not the right permission. And not the right uri. But please try... surprise me ;-)

Comment: Which permission do you mean? setAllowContentAccess(true)? I set it and it did not help.

Comment: Hmm, but what should I do with the url reported by "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" function? It reports me these broken uris. How to deal with them? I set the permission setAllowContentAccess(true). First uri is correct, I get it from SAF. All other uris are created by webview, like you said. But if I pass them to webview.loadUrl(uri), then the page is not loaded.

Comment: "Why?" -- among other things, you are only getting rights to one file, not other files that happen to be available on that device.

Answer (score 0):

```
  webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);


  webView.loadUrl(uri.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question. I found the problem, but I am not sure how to fix that.